# What lifecycle method do I use to initialize data in React Redux Component?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

I have a component that shows a list of objects that I retrieve from the server. My implementation looks like the following. I have tried several lifecycle methods, but they all seem to not do what I need.

I need the code in `xxxxLifeCycleMethod(...)` to be invoked once ideally, but it would be fine if it was invoked when those properties change (which they really wont). My best guess for this would be `componentWillReceiveProps(...)`

```
 class Home extends Component {

  xxxxxLifeCycleMethod(){
    let { userId,token } = this.props;
    this.props.dispatch(loadMyList(userId,token));
 }

 ...

 //Component Implementation

 ...

 function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    userId:state.get('profile').current.id,
    token:state.get('application').auth.token,
  }
 }
```

Comment: Well did you try `componentWillReceiveProps`? What about `componentDidMount`?

Comment: I think you want `componentWillMount` as `componentWillReceiveProps` is called every time props change while `componentWillMount` is invoked just once before the component is initially rendered. [Source](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html)

Comment: componentDidMount will match your use case, get's called only once when the component mounts. componentWillReceiveProps will not get called the first time the component mounts but for future prop updates

Answer (score 1):

according to [this link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/reactjs/reactjs_component_life_cycle.htm) :

```
componentWillMount is executed before rendering, on both server and client side.
```

and  this

```
componentDidMount is executed after first render only on the client side. This is where AJAX requests and DOM or state updates should occur. This method is also used for integration with other JavaScript frameworks and any functions with delayed execution like setTimeout or setInterval. We are using it to update the state so we can trigger the other lifecycle methods.
```

i think you should use `componentWillMount` Life Cycle.